# Execute PHP Code on ASP Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, asp-classic

Does anyone know if there is a file handler (or some other directive) that can be added to an .htaccess file that will force PHP code to execute within an ASP page? It's working currently on client's site but it will not on new server at GoDaddy under Plesk.

This is what's currently in the .htaccess file on the site that works, but it is not working on the new server.

```
<FilesMatch "\.asp$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you say "asp page" do you just mean a file with the ".asp" extension?

Comment: Yes, there is no actual ASP code on the page that I can tell. It's a .asp file with PHP includes that call in other ASP files and MySQL queries.

Comment: Is GoDaddy set up to allow .htaccess overrides? Maybe that is what you need to change.

Comment: I'm not sure if they are or not. It seems like no matter what I add to the .htaccess file nothing happens so I'm not even sure if the server is recognizing it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have PHP and ASP code on one page.

You cannot include PHP file to ASP code, and you cannot include ASP file to PHP code.

But you could have PHP and ASP pages inside one project.

You could have file with file extension .ASP but inside will be PHP code (and only PHP code). For handle such file you should make changes in IIS:

[image]

Comment: I said there is no ASP code on the page, but that it is a file with the .asp extension that is executing PHP code.

Comment: try to change "Application extension" as showed in sample

Comment: There isn't that level of access in the GoDaddy account admin panel, which is why I'm hoping to accomplish this with .htaccess.